# Up cast and Down cast

Tags: java, cast

Ребята в Java без Up cast-а не можем делать прямой Down cast , я попробовал и получал CastException . `

```
class A
{

}
class B extends  A{

}
public class My {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        B ob1=new B();
        A ob=new A();
        ob1 = (B) ob;

    }
}
```

`

Comment: `A ob=new B();` и тогда можно делать Down cast.

Comment: вообще Down cast - это плохо и зачастую говорит о проблемах в архитектуре. но в целом вы приводите неочевидный пример. представьте класс А, от которого наследуются класс В и С. теперь, создавая экземпляры класса В и С, вы можете привести их переменой типа суперкласса - А. вместе с тем сделать Down cast вы модете только в том случае, если это приведение будет к тому классу (В или С), которые фактически находятся в переменной типа суперкласса А. в вашем случае вы создали экземпляр класса В, который у вас является суперклассом, его нельзя привести к его потомку классу Б.